# BigQuery error in load operation: Token invalid - Invalid token: Stateless token expired

Tags: google-bigquery

I see the following error: 
     BigQuery error in load operation: Token invalid - Invalid token:
     Stateless token expired

when I try to upload a big plain text ( or gzip'ed)  (~90Million records) file

Here is the command I am using to try to upload the data:

~/bigquery-2.0.6]$ python bq.py load --skip_leading_rows 7 -F"\t"                                                                                                                               conn_logs.conn  /scratch/conn.log   /scratch/conn.schema

If I try smaller files, data loads up just fine.

Any idea what is causing this and how can I renew the tokens so that it doesn't expire ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a bug in the way token renewal is handled by the `oauth2client` -- namely it doesn't refresh the token at the end of the upload. It's being tracked internally, but I don't think there's an ETA on a fix yet.

The easiest workaround is simply to upload the file to Google Storage, and then call load using the Google Storage path. This is pretty painless, and there's even [a nice tutorial](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/hello_bigquery#createtable).